# multiple package goals in single POM.XML file

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I want to have 2 packaging goals in my same POM.xml file. 2 packaging goals will derive 2 different jars

Comment: Can you show your pom?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really the ethos behind maven where you build a single artifact only. You can manage multiple artifacts by housing your two individual artifacts as `modules` under a parent pom (of packaging `pom`) .

For example:

pom.xml in .../com/product/parent/child1 (building child1 jar)

```
<project xmlns="...">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.product</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.product.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Child1 jar</name>

    <properties>
        ...
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                etc...
            <plugin>
        <plugins>
    <build>
    <dependencies>
    ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

pom.xml in .../com/product/parent/child2 (building child jar)

```
<project xmlns="...">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.product</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.product.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>child2</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Child2 jar</name>

    <properties>
        ...
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                etc...
            <plugin>
        <plugins>
    <build>
    <dependencies>
    ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

For completeness, here's an example of composing your jars into a separate ear artifact to be deployed. This is also housed as a module under your parent location.
pom.xml in .../com/product/parent/child-ear (building child-ear ear composing of child1 and child2 jars):

```
<project xmlns="...">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.product</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.product.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>child-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <name>Child EAR</name>

    <properties>
        ...
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                etc...
            <plugin>
        <plugins>
    <build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>    <!-- include the above jars in my child-ear -->
            <groupId>com.product.parent</groupId>
            <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.product.parent</groupId>
            <artifactId>child2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

parent pom: pom.xml in .../com/product/parent (above child1 and child2 jar poms)

```
<project xmlns="...">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    ...
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.product</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Parent Assembly</name>

    <modules>  <!-- child modules to be executed as part of this build -->
        <module>child1</module>
        <module>child2</module>
        <module>child-ear</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        ...
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                etc...
            <plugin>
        <plugins>
    <build>
</project>
```

There is some discussion of multiple module poms in:

- the [sonatype multi-module tutorial](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)

Other than that, you should get to grips with how maven does things (as it's fairly confined to support familiarity:

- [maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) to understand how maven works, that it executes goals in certain phases of a lifecycle (depending on the artifact) and that you plug into those phases.
- [maven packaging a jar](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_deploy_my_jar_in_my_remote_repository), indicating that maven promotes a single artifact approach.
- The [apache maven tutorials](http://maven.apache.org/users/index.html)  are also a necessary read.

If you wished you could have an assembly pom that unpacked and repacked dependencies into some other structure (or pack jars into wars or whatever). See the `assembly:single` mojo goal for how to use this (as it's more involvde and probably beyond the scope of your question.